# How do I parse data received in a memorystream?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I'm new to using sockets.  I have a very basic client that sends a request, and waits for a response.  The response is one stream, but has two parts.  The first part is prefixed with ANS and is a set of key/value pairs in this form: KEY:Value with each pair on a separate line.

The second part of the response is prefixed by RCT and this is pre-formatted text that needs to be send directly to a printer.

So what would be the best way to extract both parts of the response, and in the first part, get each Key:Value pair.   I might not even need them all, but I have to look at each one to see what the values are then decide what to do with it.

I'm currently writing the response out to a textbox just to understand what its doing, but now I need to actually do something with the data.

Here's a data sample, as it is received:

```
ANS Result: Data Received                                                                
RCPRES:Q[81]
TML:123
OPP:
MRR:000000999999
<several dozen more KEY:Value pairs>
RCTNov 05 2013  04:03 pm      Trans# 123456

           <pre-formatted text>
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you, M.Babcock and Darcy for your clear explanations. I'm able to wrap my brain around the logic necessary to do what I need.  I will ponder both approaches and see what I come up with.

Comment: How are you getting hold of your socket in the first place? I suspect that you may be using a network stream, which you then pipe into a memory stream. If that is the case then you may be able to bypass the memory stream and go directly into a StreamReader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you're working with the buffer once it's already completely loaded into memory, the best you could hope for is efficient array manipulation. As far as I can tell, the `MemoryStream` class is little more than a `Stream` facade over an array of bytes in memory (with proper positioning handling added, of course).

You'll be best off iterating through the stream in the smallest significant increments, so assuming your sample text is real and depending on whether the new lines are CR, LF, or CR + LF it might be one or two bytes. Iterating until you find the RCT prefix you're expecting (assuming that sequence won't be found elsewhere in the stream) should allow you to assume you're still processing KV pairs and respond accordingly.

Once you reach the RCT prefix it appears you need to switch to a fixed-width processing approach that is specific to your implementation.

As far as a high level design for this system goes, I'd probably recommend a capture/state object capable of representing each of the different possible KV pairs (assuming the fixed values still have implicit keys associated) from the message. You'd need at least 2 different parser's to process the request based on the required formats; one for explicit KV pairs in KEY:VALUE format and another implicit one for the strongly formatted portion. With these in place it's just a matter of iterating over the stream bytes and delegating portions of the message to each parser based on the "stage" of the message.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a stream as a conveyor belt with a gate which holds items. So as some other guy adds things further up the line, you end up with a buffer behind the gate. Also somewhere back from where your gate is there is a sensor, which signals the other guy to stop putting things on the line. You don't necessary know how far back that sensor is.
The other guy may be adding the items really fast (until he is signalled to pause by the sensor) or he could be adding them slowly.

You can check the number of items backed up behind the gate by calling .Peak() 
You can also read (let through the gate) one or more boxes off the line by calling .Read()

Reading a byte would be one box, reading an int would be 4 boxes; as an int is 4 bytes long.
Or you could read off an array of (say) 4 ints which would be 16 boxes/bytes

*(Off the top of my head I think if you ask to read of more data than is in the buffer then it either block (waits for the guy further up the line to send more boxes, or it throws an exception... You will need to try it and see)*

Ok now for your data. You have it pretty easy. Each key value pair is separated with a new line.
What you could do is to read off one byte and convert that to a char and check it that is a new line char if not add it to buffer to convert to a string when you finaly find one.

However that is messy and inefficient.
What you can do instead is create a reader which implements TextReader e.g., a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using you memory stream.

The StreamReader implements a ReadLine() method, which will do this for you.

Ok now in a while loop read off line by line from your socket/StreamReader.
Then check each line if it is a key value pair or the RCT thingy

If it is a KVP, add it to a List, or split it on the colon and add it to a Dictionary; or something like that, to use later

If it is the RCT thingy call ReadToEnd() concat the two strings (The RCT to newline and the ReadToEnd) and pass that on to your printer.

You will also do something to account for the ANS at the beginning. Say using the [Read(Char[], Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97e90x91%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload.